# iOS Facebook SDK 3.8 - login procedure

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

Honestly, FB is driving me a little crazy - but that's just a sidenote...

I kinda gave up finding a way of authenticating a user without leaving my app and opening Safari or the facebook app (which just breaks the whole user experience for NO apparent reason).

Anyway, since they insist, I don't have a choice. BUT: All of FB's examples handle the FBSession in the AppDelegate. IMHO, that's not where it belongs to. My App doesn't revolve entirely around FB, it's just a part of it for uploading some things to a user's timeline (IF she really wants that).
So I'd like to handle the whole FBSession-stuff in my viewController that handles the FB-upload.

But when a user authenticates, FB wants me to implement the following in my AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    // attempt to extract a token from the url
    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                        withSession:self.session];
}
```

But at this stage, I don't have `self.session` in my AppDelegate. How do I pass this on to my ViewController? Can I store it somewhere?
I found a class (http://barrycenter.com/BAM!coding/2011/07/simplifying-facebook-ios-sdk/) which creates a Singleton. But it's for an outdated version of the SDK and I can't figure out how to change it so it works with the new SDK.
Creating a Singleton seems like a good idea to me - so could anybody point me into the right direction how I'd do this with the latest SDK (3.8)?

Comment: Users are forced to FB app or Safari only if they don't have an FB account registered in their device settings.

You use this application method to catch incoming calls from other apps and analyze the URL schema. Your code tries to open Facebook app here. When you login with facebook, e.g. with [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions] and the app switches to FB/Safari and gets back - it should go back automatically to the calling view controller. Instead of [FBAppCall handleOpenURL], try

BOOL result = [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
return result;

Comment: Thanks for that hint, Tal. I tried to implement that. But it doesn't seem to transfer the session to my ViewController... I'm checking for an active session in viewDidLoad with FBSession.activeSession - the result is always 0

[edit] it seems it does... THANKS!!!